# What happen if don't call stop() function in Android Google Analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've been looking through the code of the [GoogleIO Android app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) and I notice the their did not call `stop()` function on the GoogleAnalytics' instance. What will happen if we don't call `stop()`?

This is the code:

```
package com.google.android.apps.iosched.util;

import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Helper singleton class for the Google Analytics tracking library.
 */
public class AnalyticsUtils {
    private static final String TAG = "AnalyticsUtils";

    GoogleAnalyticsTracker mTracker;
    private Context mApplicationContext;

    /**
     * The analytics tracking code for the app.
     */
    // TODO: insert your Analytics UA code here.
    private static final String UACODE = "INSERT_YOUR_ANALYTICS_UA_CODE_HERE";

    private static final int VISITOR_SCOPE = 1;
    private static final String FIRST_RUN_KEY = "firstRun";
    private static final boolean ANALYTICS_ENABLED = true;

    private static AnalyticsUtils sInstance;

    /**
     * Returns the global {@link AnalyticsUtils} singleton object, creating one if necessary.
     */
    public static AnalyticsUtils getInstance(Context context) {
        if (!ANALYTICS_ENABLED) {
            return sEmptyAnalyticsUtils;
        }

        if (sInstance == null) {
            if (context == null) {
                return sEmptyAnalyticsUtils;
            }
            sInstance = new AnalyticsUtils(context);
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    private AnalyticsUtils(Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            // This should only occur for the empty Analytics utils object.
            return;
        }

        mApplicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mTracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();

        // Unfortunately this needs to be synchronous.
        mTracker.start(UACODE, 300, mApplicationContext);

        Log.d(TAG, "Initializing Analytics");

        // Since visitor CV's should only be declared the first time an app runs, check if
        // it's run before. Add as necessary.
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mApplicationContext);
        final boolean firstRun = prefs.getBoolean(FIRST_RUN_KEY, true);
        if (firstRun) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Analytics firstRun");

            String apiLevel = Integer.toString(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
            String model = Build.MODEL;
            mTracker.setCustomVar(1, "apiLevel", apiLevel, VISITOR_SCOPE);
            mTracker.setCustomVar(2, "model", model, VISITOR_SCOPE);

            // Close out so we never run this block again, unless app is removed & =
            // reinstalled.
            prefs.edit().putBoolean(FIRST_RUN_KEY, false).commit();
        }
    }

    public void trackEvent(final String category, final String action, final String label,
            final int value) {
        // We wrap the call in an AsyncTask since the Google Analytics library writes to disk
        // on its calling thread.
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    mTracker.trackEvent(category, action, label, value);
                    Log.d(TAG, "iosched Analytics trackEvent: "
                            + category + " / " + action + " / " + label + " / " + value);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // We don't want to crash if there's an Analytics library exception.
                    Log.w(TAG, "iosched Analytics trackEvent error: "
                            + category + " / " + action + " / " + label + " / " + value, e);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public void trackPageView(final String path) {
        // We wrap the call in an AsyncTask since the Google Analytics library writes to disk
        // on its calling thread.
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    mTracker.trackPageView(path);
                    Log.d(TAG, "iosched Analytics trackPageView: " + path);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // We don't want to crash if there's an Analytics library exception.
                    Log.w(TAG, "iosched Analytics trackPageView error: " + path, e);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    /**
     * Empty instance for use when Analytics is disabled or there was no Context available.
     */
    private static AnalyticsUtils sEmptyAnalyticsUtils = new AnalyticsUtils(null) {
        @Override
        public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label, int value) {}

        @Override
        public void trackPageView(String path) {}
    };
}
```

As you can see, they start the tracker with 5 minutes interval `mTracker.start(UACODE, 300, mApplicationContext);` but never call the `mTracker.stop()` method. Will there be any consequences? Does it mean the service will dispatch the data even when the app is closed or stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EasyTracker** - I found [this blog entry](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/12/google-analytics-enhancements-for.html) in the google analytics blog. There they describe an EasyTracker class, that wraps the normal Tracker class and has some nice features.

- Configuration via resource file (no coding needed)
- Everything's done in a separate thread (not in the ui-thread as with the normal Tracker)
- ...

And this EasyTracker does not need to be stopped explicity either.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be happen much -- when you close or stop the app, and even if it still lives in the background and there's no activity anymore, no new data will be gathered (because no one invokes track() anymore. So I think it's just good manners to explicitly stop the tracker.

Comment: It could be like what you said. Is there any documentation or article about it?